# How to Approximate Partial Derivatives from Contour Map

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

[A problem of approximating partial derivatives from a given contour map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aacq5.jpg)
Hi, I would like to know the connection between a contour map and partial derivatives. I understand that partial derivatives give a slope to the tangent line on a specific point but I cannot see the connection between it and a contour map

Comment: I would also like to know.  I've completely forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

As the $z$ values are given, the contour map is a representation of a function $z=f(x,y)$. Hence graphical and numerical methods can be used to estimate the partial derivatives.

Comment: Oh, I see.  That's what the $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ are.

Comment: @ChrisCuster: yep.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, only $c)$ has the numbers in the right places.  For we do see that $f(1,1)=5$ and $f(-4,2)=0$.  For instance, for $f_y$, we hold $x$ fixed, and vary $y$.  Thus we get an estimate $f_y(1,1)=\dfrac{4-5}{1.25-1}$.  We can see from the contours that, increasing $y$ a little at $(1,1)$, $z$ is about $4$.  Etc

Comment: I guess I'm supposed to use the equation from the definition of partial derivatives. I can kind of see where I can get the nominator based from your last sentence, but I don't know how to get the denominator. Where does the (1.25-1) come from?

Comment: I find it a little arbitrary, but the point seems to be that, varying $y$ just a little ($0.25$), we wind up on the contour $4$.  Remember $x$ is fixed.

Comment: I guess it isn't arbitrary; it just may not be that good an estimate.